# How to add complete child LWC component HTML content in PDF file?

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf

I have two child LWC components and I have merged in parent component. Now I want to create PDF file which will be having data of HTML content of both the child HTML component. Using below code I am able to add content in PDF:

```
let editor = this.template.querySelector('lightning-formatted-rich-text');
pdf.text(editor.value, 20, 20);
```

Similarly I want to add child component content into PDF. I tried below but its not working:

```
let childData = this.template.querySelector('c-child1-doc-generation');
pdf.text(childData.value, 20, 20);
```

[Invalid arguments passed to jsPDF.text].

Can someone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Is that the exact error message you're getting? What is the 'input' that's invalid?  Please edit your question with more information.

Comment: Hi @NickCook,  I have used jsPDF library for pdf creation. So its giving me below error:  [Invalid arguments passed to jsPDF.text]                                                                                c-child1-doc-generation is a child component in my case.

Comment: Did you get a solution to the above issue @VaniMude